# Modify default value of field from mongo-engine django

Tags: django, mongodb, field, default

I have the following models

```
Class xyz(Document):
    done_project_categories = ListField(StringField(), 
        default=['All', 'Residential', 'Corporate', 'Commercial'])
```

I want to change the default value as following and migrate onto mongodb

```
Class xyz(Document):
    done_project_categories = ListField(StringField(), 
        default=['All', 'Residential', 'Corporate', 'Commercial', 'Cafes'])
```

I am not able migrate onto datebase and looking for exact command to migrate the changes onto mongodb.

I am using mongo-engine for to interact with the database from Django.